# Ampscript Block If/Then With Null Value

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, email-template

So I have the following Ampscript block at the header of my email:

```
%%[

Var @current_term_end_date, @rows 

if Rowcount(@rows)>0 then 
 Set @row = Row(@rows, 1) 
 Set @current_term_end_date = Field(@row, "current_term_end_date") 
endif

]%%
```

The inline AMpscript is set as `%%=format(@Current_term_end_date,"MM/dd/yyyy")=%%` 
so that when that date value is pulled in it displays in the proper format.

Some of our rows don't have the value in that cell, so I'm wanting to configure the block AMPscript so that it will pull in "N/A" into the email. Essentially, I'm wanting to input a conditional into the middle of the If/Then. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this, where you only format the date if you know it's not blank:

```
%%[

Var @current_term_end_date, @rows 

/* lookup code here */

Set @current_term_end_date = "N/A"

if Rowcount(@rows) > 0 then 

 Set @row = Row(@rows, 1) 
 Set @current_term_end_date = Field(@row, "current_term_end_date")

 if not empty(@current_term_end_date) then
   Set @current_term_end_date = format(@Current_term_end_date,"MM/dd/yyyy") 
 endif

endif

]%% 

%%=v(@current_term_end_date)=%%
```